# Draw bounding boxes on document

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I want to draw bounding boxes around black boxes but unable to do so, attached code at the bottom. Please correct my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [tutorial page](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

> In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.

You'll have to invert the image. You can use [bitwise_not](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not).

Comment: Why did you accept it? Also, why did you remove your code and images?